# How can I get results of arrays in many Objects in Angular or Javascript?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, arrays, ionic-framework

I need a help in this question:

I have objects with arrays. I need get the values in the arrays to send to the server.

My question in Image:

[image: screenshot]

---

This is the code I print in the console:

```
var cart = sharedCartService.cart;
console.log(cart);
```

How I can get this datas?

Comment: From your image, you don't have two objects with arrays, you have one array with two objects. Also, it's not very clear what you are asking. You access array data with standard array notation: `cart[0].cart_item_id` etc.

Comment: what is that you are looking for ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In javascript either you put values in an array:

```
var array = [1, 2, 3, 4];
```

that can be objects:

```
var array [
 {id: 1},
 {id: 2}
];
```

But you can't put key value pairs in an array

```
// not valid
var array = [id: 1, name: sdf];
```

Only objects can have key value pairs, arrays only have values.

In your json the keys `add`, `decrement`, `find`, etc are key value pairs and making your array not valid.

What you need to do is to put those in a third object or make the whole thing an object by replacing `[]` by `{}`

Once you have a valid object or array you can use for in to loop over the properties of your object or calling them directly with the dot notation or looping through the objects in your array.

https://developer.mozilla.org/fr/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Instructions/for...in